# Can you create a temporary bond in between an atom and a filter by electrically charging the filter?

Tags: electrochemistry, bond

I want to be able to turn a filter on and off by electrically charging the filter so that it creates a temporary bond that blocks up the filter then, by discharging the filter, releasing the temporary bonds and allowing particles through again. Is this possible?

Comment: This is what an N-95 mask does, but is always turned on.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_precipitator

Comment: You about 100 years late in applying for a patent ( gas phase). Cottrell precipitator is the first name that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, you *can* increase and decrease flow through an *osmotic* filter with electricity. The process is called [electro-osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro-osmosis). This can even be used to create a pressure differential in the [electroosmotic pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroosmotic_pump).